# Changing default value of User Default boolean Swift

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, default

I have the code:

```
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if let branchcheck = userDefaults.boolForKey("someBooleanValue") as Bool? {

        println("found boolean as \(branchcheck)")

    }
```

This is grand, only when nothing has been added to user defaults this automatically returns 'false'.

I want all settings to be 'true' by default.

How is this accomplished?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According [NSUserDefaults/AccessingPreferenceValues](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AccessingPreferenceValues/AccessingPreferenceValues.html) Apple recommends to register all default values, for example

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let appDefaults = ["someBooleanValue" : true]
userDefaults.registerDefaults(appDefaults)
```

this procedure does not write anything in the preference file, but those values are defined as the default values for the appropriate keys

**Swift 3**

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
let appDefaults: [String:Any] = ["someBooleanValue" : true, 
                                 "someStringValue" : "foo"]
userDefaults.register(defaults: appDefaults)
```